# How to add non scribble file to a scribble based website

Tags: html, racket, scribble

I can use [`image`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html?q=image#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt%29._image%29%29) to embed an image in my scribble document, and the render function will copy it to the target destination. Now, I would also like to include files with my document that is not an image, such as an MP3 or PDF file that can be downloaded.

Additionally, I can't just include the file in the source folder and link to it, because if I render the document into a different target folder, it does not get copied.

Finally, I know I can just create the target directory by hand, and paste the file there. Or I can modify whatever file I'm using to build my document to copy the file. This is not satisfying though because now I have to track the image in two places. The `.scrbl` source file, and either the target directory or the build file.

So, is there a way in scribble that I can include a non scribble (or image) file such as an MP3 or PDF such that the render function knows to grab it and include it with the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is a bit of a kludge, you can combine `image` with [`hyperlink`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html?q=hyperlink#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt%29._hyperlink%29%29) to get your desired result. You use the `image` function to get the `render` function to copy the file, and `hyperlink` to add a link to it. Your document will look something like:

```
Here is a @image{file.mp3}@hyperlink["file.mp3"]{file}.
```

This works because the `image` function also expects a list of extensions to try to embed, but this list defaults to the empty list, and such it won't embed the file, but only copy it into the destination. You can then use `hyperlink` to link to the now copied `file.mp3` file.

You can combine this into one operation with the following function:

```
(define (embed-file file . content)
  (list
    (image file)
    (apply hyperlink file content)))
```

And now you can use `embed-file` in your own document with:

```
Here is a @embed-file["file.mp3"]{file}.
```

(I should note that this idea came from [Ben Lerner](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/blerner/).)

Answer (score 2):

I took over somebody's code base and they had solved this issue using the [solution above/below mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39772632/411495) provided by Leif Andersen. However, this caused problems when linking to files that were part of subfolders in the source directory. The file in question was moved to the root of the output directory, while the hyperlink did not correctly update. Instead, I found the following less hack-y solution.

You can make use of the [`link-resource`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fhtml-properties..rkt%29._link-resource%29%29) structure of the [`scribble/html-properties`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html#%28mod-path._scribble%2Fhtml-properties%29) module. This expects the path of the original file. You place this `link-resource` into a [`style`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fcore..rkt%29._style%29%29) struct of the [`scribble/core`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html) module. Finally, this style is passed as an argument to `hyperlink`.

Putting it all together, the `embed-file` function instead becomes

```
(define (embed-file file . content)
  (apply hyperlink
         file
         content
         #:style (style "place-resources-in-output-folder" ; name
                        (list (link-resource file)))))
```

Where the `"place-resources-in-output-folder"` is just a name I give to the style.

This ensures the files are both moved to the root output folder and correctly linked.